# intentionally fail setting a php variable

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

I am at a loss for how to intention make this fail

```
if($a = aFunctionIMade()){
  //do something
}
else{
  //throw error
}
```

I have seen this used with certain predefined functions like

```
while ($tableRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, as I was writing this question I realized the answer...

from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned.
>
> `$a = ($b = 4) + 5; // $a is equal to 9 now, and $b has been set to 4.`

So if the function `aFunctionIMade()` returns `false`, then the assignmesnt expression's value would be `false` and fail the `if` statement sending me to the `else` and throw the error.